# JHipster email server Configuration

Tags: jhipster

Based on the [email service configuration document](https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/011_tip_configuring_email_in_jhipster.html), I configure the email server for gmail. I get the following error:

```
| 2018-04-26 16:52:43.049  WARN 8 --- [ader-Executor-1] c.abc.myapp.service.MailService   : Email could not be sent to user '<an email address>': Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuK
myapp-app_1            | 534-5.7.14 FS7l_SlKGMmQ4NUwOUI8hV4s4DFyO9Ajb9jIQNPmd_oPTPeYKvPez2X9WTyRxci1tqFD3j
myapp-app_1            | 534-5.7.14 EIuDoA4ekrQEvFUoHHTBkBpXLPSd9WyK4OfnClEVc7LOKqRRurLkCzm7YPSVjScsoCCSfY
myapp-app_1            | 534-5.7.14 ZDkTMZpbTNSpjO7cLfFPhrk8YyKz6-Zr6PUh8diPloWF7dCGQDHb3U8Pupum7w8ZooCS6D
myapp-app_1            | 534-5.7.14 W4a_ecgcmwyU-yqYVU41sE9Ejns_E> Please log in via your web browser and
myapp-app_1            | 534-5.7.14 then try again.
myapp-app_1            | 534-5.7.14  Learn more at
myapp-app_1            | 534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 s65sm52666197pfj.124 - gsmtp
```

I follow the instruction and get a page with the following message:

> Account access enabled
>   Please try signing in to your Google account again from your new device or application.

However, I still get the erro.

So, I try outlook email server.

```
myapp-app_1            | 2018-04-26 17:22:08.398  WARN 8 --- [ader-Executor-1] c.abc.myapp.service.MailService   : Email could not be sent to user '<an email address>': Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. 16.55847:CB210000, 17.43559:0000000094000000000000000000000000000000, 20.52176:140FCB820E00101097010000, 20.50032:140FCB827E171010AA010000, 0.35180:0A007282, 255.23226:D1010000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:0A006784, 16.55847:B4000000, 17.43559:0000000068010000000000000000000000000000, 20.52176:140FCB820E0010100A00F736, 20.50032:140FCB827E1710100A00F836, 0.35180:EF010000, 255.23226:40000730, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:32000000, 255.17082:DC040000, 0.27745:0A001880, 4.21921:DC040000, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:07020000, 0.37692:B4000000, 0.37948:B4000000, 5.33852:00000000534D545000343345, 4.56248:DC040000, 7.40748:010000000000010B41344539, 7.57132:000000000000000000000000, 1.63016:32000000, 4.39640:DC040000, 8.45434:171C0100364C1BE8000000000000000000303833, 5.10786:0000000031352E32302E303731352E3031343A434F31505231384D42303833373A66663930326535392D346362332D346164632D383633322D36636464303663626165666600503000000000, 255.1750:02017368, 255.31418:5B030000, 0.22753:80030400, 255.21817:DC040000, 4.60547:DC040000, 0.21966:7E010000, 4.30158:DC040000 [Hostname=CO1PR18MB0837.namprd18.prod.outlook.com]
```

I know they are not a JHipster problem, but I am wondering how JHipster users solve them.

Comment: Gmail: have you granted access to less secure apps? Outlook: does your `From` header match your username?

Comment: Also, from my experience, sending Spam email from a personal Gmail account promptly causes the account to get blocked, and I wouldn't be surprised if this was the case for Outlook as well. I'd recommend using a commercial email service like [mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) right from the start. Otherwise, you might find that afer a couple rounds of testing, sending emails mysteriously fails

Comment: Thanks for your info. I will look into it.